# Swift Radio App--What to do about non-standard link?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm working on a Swift app in Xcode to play a radio station. However, the radio station's streaming link is non-standard, with numbers in it. How would I be able to use this link to stream from? Thank you very much!

https://us8.listen2myradio.com:2199/tunein/ghloisvo.pls

Comment: Are you planning to use `NSURL`? It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The number is simply a port.  You can retrieve the stream via any NSURLSession/NSURLSessionStreamTask.  The generic form of a URL is:

```
protocol://servername:port/relative_url?query_string
```

If the protocol is http, the port defaults to 80.  If the protocol is https the default port is 443.  You can override the port though to whatever value that the server is running.

Something along these lines might work:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.streamTaskWithHostName("us8.listen2myradio.com", port: 2199)
```